# leaflet geojson - point to layer set z index on some icons?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm currently using GeoJSON and `pointToLayer` to create icons on my map, I would like some of those icons to appear on top.

I have a property in my GeoJSON called `z_index` which on some of the values I set to 100 and others null, (through research I think I can influence the ordering with this?) but the plugins and things I've tried so far aren't working (https://gist.github.com/up209d/4c68f2391f2302e510eb81aa8bcd4514 for example)

My current config is as per the below:

```
var geo_data = {{ geo_data|safe }}

{% for st in site_types %}
var z_index = null
var {{ st.safe_name }} = L.geoJSON(geo_data, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.geometry.coordinates != "None") {
            return feature.properties.type === "{{ st.name }}";
        }
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon(
                        {
                            icon: feature.properties.icon, 
                            markerColor: feature.properties.color, 
                            prefix: 'fa', 
                            iconColor: 'white',
                        }
                    )
                }
            );
    },

    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('<h3><a href="/sites/site/'+feature.properties.site_id+'">'+feature.properties.popupContent+'</a></h3>');
}
});
{% endfor %}
```

here's the sample of an icon that should be ontop at the moment, looks like its z-index is being set to 1901

```
<div class="awesome-marker-icon-darkred awesome-marker leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -17px; margin-top: -42px; width: 35px; height: 45px; transform: translate3d(512px, 901px, 0px); z-index: 1901; outline: none;"><i class="fa fa-server  icon-white"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markers have a [`zIndexOffset` property](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#marker-zindexoffset) :

> **zIndexOffset** (number, default: 0)
>   By default, marker images zIndex is set automatically based on its
>   latitude. Use this option if you want to put the marker on top of all
>   others (or below), specifying a high value like 1000 (or high negative
>   value, respectively).

Your `pointToLayer` function could set this option according to your `z_index` property. Something like:

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    // beware the exact type of your property
    // adapt your test to your context
    var zindex = feature.properties.z_index && feature.properties.z_index !== "null";

    return L.marker(latlng, {
        zIndexOffset: zindex  ? 1000 : 0,
        icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon(
                    {
                        icon: feature.properties.icon, 
                        markerColor: feature.properties.color, 
                        prefix: 'fa', 
                        iconColor: 'white',
                    }
                )
            }
        );
},
```

And a demo

```js
var points = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -104.9998241,
                    39.7471494
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
             color: 'green',
              z_index: null
            }
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -104.9983545,
                    39.7502833
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
               z_index: 1000
            }
        }
  ]
};
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.74739, -105], 13);


L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
   '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
   'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1
 }).addTo(map);
  
var iconGreen = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'glass', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'green'});
var iconRed = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'spinner', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'red', spin:true});

L.geoJSON(points, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      var color = feature.properties.color || 'red';
        var zIndex = feature.properties.z_index || 0;
        return L.marker(latlng, {
         zIndexOffset: zIndex,
         icon: color === 'green' ? iconGreen: iconRed
       });
  }
 }).addTo(map);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.min.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Hi this hasn't seemed to work, im looking for only some of the icons in that layer to be on top of others, based on feature.properties.z_index. do they need to be in a separate layer? ive added to the question a sample of one of the icons that should be on top

Comment: Do you have an example as a snippet like I did or in a Fiddle or equivalent? My tests work as expected. See the snippet or https://jsfiddle.net/y5wbo9j2/ or https://jsfiddle.net/y5wbo9j2/2/

Comment: just managed to recreate the issues here https://jsfiddle.net/ajwill0/6jvgcmd4/1/ Thanks

Comment: Your null values are strings, not JS null values. See https://jsfiddle.net/0sym54vx/1/ for a working example. I'll update my answer